# Cannot add or update a child row SQL

Tags: sql

Я пытаюсь добавить новый объект в таблицу SQL, но оно отказывает и выдаёт ошибку:

"ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lod`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `uid` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

Я так понимаю, что ошибка заключается в том, что айди в двух таблицах не совпадает, но оно совпадает.

Вот сам запрос:

```
INSERT INTO posts(`title`, `desc`, `img`, `uid`, `cat`) VALUES ('sdas', '<p>dsadsd</p>', 7, 6, 'art')
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что id 6 не существует в users, но оно существует.

Доказательство:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: *CONSTRAINT uid FOREIGN KEY (**id**) REFERENCES users (id)* - я выделил ссылающееся поле. Сравни с тем, в которое ты кладёшь абы существующее значение 6...

Comment: @Akina Я же показал, что действительно такое id существует (картинка снизу), даже выделил красным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внешний ключ говорит, что `posts.id` равен `users.id`, тогда как в запросе значение 6 пишется в поле `posts.uid`, а поле `id` вообще не упоминается.

Ещё раз. На всякий случай. Внешний ключ связывает поле `id` (две буквы). Запрос пишет значение в поле `uid` (три буквы).

Comment: На самом деле у меня связан posts.uid и users.id, а posts.id вообще не причëм, я вообще не понимаю в чëм проблема.

Comment: @ИмператорИнтеллектуализма *На самом деле у меня связан posts.uid и users.id* ГДЕ? Добавьте в вопрос вывод SHOW CREATE TABLE для обеих таблиц. Но я больше верю не Вашим словам, а сообщению сервера, которое чётко показывает, что связаны именно `posts.id` и `users.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка "ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" означает, что при добавлении новой записи в таблицу "posts" вы пытаетесь использовать значение в колонке "uid" (которая является внешним ключом, ссылающимся на таблицу "users"), которое не существует в таблице "users".

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно убедиться, что в таблице "users" существует запись с id=6. Если эта запись существует, то возможно, что в запросе на вставку вы указали неправильные индексы колонок или неправильный тип данных. Проверьте, что вы указываете значения для каждой колонки в правильном порядке и что они соответствуют типу данных, ожидаемому в схеме таблицы.

Например, если тип данных колонки "uid" является целым числом, то вы должны указывать целое число, а не строку, и так далее. Убедитесь, что вы указываете значения для всех колонок, указанных в запросе, и что типы данных соответствуют типам данных, ожидаемым в схеме таблицы.

Если вы уверены, что указываете правильные значения и типы данных, то возможно, что в таблице "users" уже существует запись с id=6, но она была удалена с помощью оператора DELETE CASCADE, указанного в ограничении FOREIGN KEY. В этом случае вам нужно либо обновить значение внешнего ключа в таблице "posts" так, чтобы оно ссылалось на существующую запись в таблице "users", либо удалить ограничение FOREIGN KEY, чтобы избежать этой ошибки в будущем.

Comment: Друг, как запись с id=6 может быть удалена, если я буквально скинул скриншот в вопросе, где выделил красным существование этой записи?